# Openlayers 3 detect the layer by mouse move

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features, openlayers

I wanna do something like this ;

[Openlayers 3 Vector Layer Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/vector-layer.html?q=feature)

But I don't want to one layer, 3 or more layer on the map and get feature like the example.

How can I separate the layer programmatically ?

```
    if (feature) {
    info.innerHTML = feature.getId() + ': ' + feature.get('name');
  } else {
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }
```

Because I will need to change the `feature.get('name')` properties each layer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to be able to change a property on all or some of the features (on separate layers) on the map.

From the `ol.map` object, you can get the `layergroup` property.  This will give you access to all the layers on the map, you can then just do something like:

```
var layers = map.get('layergroup').getLayersArray();
for (var i in layers) {
  // The features are inside a source object
  var features = layers[i].getSource().getFeatures();
  for (var f in features) {
    // Set properties based on whatever logic 
    features[f].set('foo', 'bar');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get this error message : `TypeError: map.get(...).getLayersArray is not a function`

Comment: Sorry about that, it is odd though - that is part of the API: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/layer/layergroup.js#L181

but if you do `map.get('layergroup').getLayers()` it should give you an `ol.Collection` which you can get an array from if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The basic trick is loop through the features and concatenate result to the innerHTML.

```
var info = document.getElementById('info');
info.innerHTML = ''; // clears out the current content
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  info.innerHTML += feature.getId() + ': ' + feature.get('name') + '<br/>';
});
```

Comment: OK, I understand, but i had to change the property, because each layer has a different element. For example, One of them has 'name', one of them 'area'. I think, if conditions maybe help. But i didn't catch the layer.

Comment: you got it. Just look at the example in the answer: `forEachFeatureAtPixel` is called with with the feature *and* the layer as argument.